# windows c# application as windows task scheduler

Tags: c#

I am new to c# programming but I don't have any idea of how to make my application run as windows task scheduler.
I have 8 buttons on my application and want to execute them on specific time on task scheduler.. is it possible to do it.. please help me..this is my code... I have changed the ip addressses.

```
private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)// 1)first download database to local system.
{
    string _ftpURL = @"11.21.196.48";  //Host URL or address of the SFTP server
    //string _ftpURL = @"11.11.11.2";  
    string _UserName = "add"; //User Name of the SFTP server
    string _Password = "rr"; //Password of the SFTP server
    int _Port = 2222; //Port No of the SFTP server (if any)
    string _ftpDirectory = "/home/root/systools/WM/WebMobility.db"; //The directory in SFTP server where the files will be uploaded

    string LocalDirectory = "F:\\Explor\\final test"; //Local directory from where the files will be uploaded
    Sftp Connection = new Sftp(_ftpURL, _UserName, _Password);
    Connection.Connect(_Port);
    Connection.Get(_ftpDirectory, LocalDirectory);
    Connection.Close();
}

private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//2) Extracting data  from DATABASE and saving it as csv.
{
    SQLiteConnection m_dbConnection;
    //m_dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source= C:/Users/IT-Administrator/Desktop/WebMobility.db; Version=3;");

    m_dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection("Data source = F:/Explor/final test/WebMobility.db; Version=3;");
    ; pwd=3xpl0rp1; Convert Zero Datetime=true;");
    m_dbConnection.Open();

    SQLiteCommand myCommand = new SQLiteCommand();
    myCommand.Connection = m_dbConnection;


    myCommand.CommandText = "select CompanyId,DateTime,Serial,ShortDeviceId,MatricolaA,Upper(Targa),CommonRoadDescription,RoadCivicNumber,GpsAddress,VerbaliVehicleTypeDescription,VehicleBrandDescription,VehicleModelDescription,CommonColorVehicleDescription,VerbaliRuleOneCode,VerbaliRuleOneDescription,VerbaliClosedNoteDescription,VerbaliRuleOnePoints,VerbaliMissedNotificationDescription  from  VerbaliData";
    //myCommand.Connection = myConn;
    DataTable data = new DataTable();
    SQLiteDataAdapter myAdapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(myCommand);
    //myAdapter.SelectCommand = myCommand;
    myAdapter.Fill(data);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = data;
    this.dataGridView1.Refresh();
    if (dataGridView1.RowCount > 0)
    {
        string value = "";
        DataGridViewRow dr = new DataGridViewRow();
        StreamWriter swOut = new StreamWriter("F:/Explor/final test/finaltest12.csv");

        //write header rows to csv
        for (int i = 0; i <= dataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            if (i > 0)
            {
                swOut.Write(",");
            }
            swOut.Write(dataGridView1.Columns[i].HeaderText);
        }

        swOut.WriteLine();

        //write DataGridView rows to csv
        for (int j = 0; j <= dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; j++)
        {
            if (j > 0)
            {
                swOut.WriteLine();
            }

            dr = dataGridView1.Rows[j];

            for (int i = 0; i <= dataGridView1.Columns.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                if (i > 0)
                {
                    swOut.Write(",");
                }

                value = dr.Cells[i].Value.ToString();
                //replace comma's with spaces
                value = value.Replace(',', ' ');
                //replace embedded newlines with spaces
                value = value.Replace(Environment.NewLine, " ");

                swOut.Write(value);
            }
        }
        swOut.Close();
    }

    m_dbConnection.Close();
}

//158.125.162.06; Database=synctest; Uid=root; Pwd=faithful

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)// 3) upload tickets data from explor as csv to tickets table.
{

    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("Data source = 15.25.12.08; database = test;uid=rrr ;pwd=fsssss ;Convert Zero Datetime=true;");
    DataTable db = new DataTable();


    string strLoadData = "LOAD DATA LOCAL  INFILE 'F:/Explor/final test/finaltest12.csv' INTO TABLE tickets  FIELDS  terminated by ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"'  lines terminated by '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES (SiteId,DateTime,Serial,DeviceId,AgentAID,VehicleRegistration,CarPark,SpaceNumber,GpsAddress,VehicleType,VehicleMake,VehicleModel,VehicleColour,IssueReasonCode,IssueReason,NoticeLocation,Points,Notes)";
    MySqlCommand cmd1 = new MySqlCommand(strLoadData, conn);


    cmd1.CommandTimeout = 6000;


    cmd1.Connection = conn;
    conn.Open();
    cmd1.Prepare();
    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();


}
```

Comment: Are you saying you want your program to run all the time, then *do things* at a certain time?  Or, do you want the operating system to run your program at a certain time?

Comment: operating system to run at certain time

Comment: So what's not working about adding it as a Scheduled Windows Task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can't call UI Element from Task Scheduler. You can call a program with a parameter that will execute without UI!**

First, change your code to extract all process in different methods and call those methods in the button_click events.

From your code, it is :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Process1();
}

// public is important
public void Process1()
{
    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("Data source = 15.25.12.08; database = test;uid=rrr ;pwd=fsssss ;Convert Zero Datetime=true;");
    DataTable db = new DataTable();

    string strLoadData = "LOAD DATA LOCAL  INFILE 'F:/Explor/final test/finaltest12.csv' INTO TABLE tickets  FIELDS  terminated by ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"'  lines terminated by '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES (SiteId,DateTime,Serial,DeviceId,AgentAID,VehicleRegistration,CarPark,SpaceNumber,GpsAddress,VehicleType,VehicleMake,VehicleModel,VehicleColour,IssueReasonCode,IssueReason,NoticeLocation,Points,Notes)";
    MySqlCommand cmd1 = new MySqlCommand(strLoadData, conn);

    cmd1.CommandTimeout = 6000;

    cmd1.Connection = conn;
    conn.Open();
    cmd1.Prepare();
    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
}
```

Do this for the 8 buttons.

Then, in the start of the programm, you can switch with a argument :

```
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    //Application.Run(new Form1());

    Form1 form = new Form1();

    String[] arguments = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
    if (arguments.Count() > 1)
    {
        Int16 valueArgument = Int16.Parse(arguments[1]);
        switch(valueArgument)
        {
            case 1 :
                form.Process1();
                break;
            case 2:
                 form.Process2();
                break;
            case 3:
                form.Process3();
                break;
            case 4:
                form.Process4();
                break;
            case 5:
                form.Process5();
                break;
            case 6:
                form.Process6();
                break;
            case 7:
                form.Process7();
                break;
            case 8:
                form.Process8();
                break;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        form.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

Argument is a number of the process you want ("1", "2", "3", ...).

Then, in the task scheduler, just call your app with argument "MyApp.exe 1", "MyApp.exe 2", etc.

If you want to have interface, just call "MyApp.exe" without argument.

Edit : that's not the proper way to do this, but it is the fastest way from your code.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the Windows Scheduler doesn't know how to press buttons on a Windows form. Normally your application would accept arguments and then do something based on them so:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // The Length property is used to obtain the length of the array. 
    // Notice that Length is a read-only property:
    Console.WriteLine("Number of command line parameters = {0}", args.Length);
    for(int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Arg[{0}] = [{1}]", i, args[i]);
    }
}
```

So, if you called:

```
myApp.exe A B C
```

You would get this output:

```
Number of command line parameters = 3
Arg[0] = [A]
Arg[1] = [B]
Arg[2] = [C]
```

From here you could do something like this:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // The Length property is used to obtain the length of the array. 
    // Notice that Length is a read-only property:
    if (args.Contains("Action1")
    {
        DoAction1();
    }
    if (args.Contains("Action2")
    {
        DoAction2();
    }
}
```

Then you would simply call:

```
myApp.exe Action1
```

This would then run your application and perform action 1. If you are using a Windows Form application you can use `String[] arguments = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();` to get the command-line arguments and apply to the above.